# Vue Apply different CSS when pinned = 1

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I'm trying to change the stylings for blogposts which are pinned. I have written some code that works A LITTLE (not as intended). So here's the code that works a little bit:

HTML: Problem here is that it posts ALL titles in every single post (but the titles of the posts that were pinned, get the styling)

```html
    <div class="row card-columns">
      <div class="card-columns">
        <div class="col justify-content-center card text-white bg-dark" v-for="(post, index) in collection" :key="index" :post="post" :index="index">
          <div class="row g-0">

            <img :src= post.image class="h-100 card-img" alt="Card image cap" style="object-fit: cover;">

            <div class="col-sm-20">
              <div class="card-body">
                <div v-bind:class="{ 'pinned': post.pinned }" v-for="(post, index) in posts" :key="index">
                  <h3 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h3></div>
                
                <p class="truncate" onclick="RevealHiddenOverflow(this)" style="text-align: left">
                    {{ post.fullText }}</p>

                <div class="btn-group flex-column flex-md-row" role="group" aria-label="btn">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#readPost" v-on:click="readPost(post, index)">Show</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editPost" v-on:click="editPost(post, index)">Edit</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" v-on:click="deletePost(post)">Delete</button>
                </div>        

              </div>
              
              <div class="card-footer">
                <p class="card-text">{{ post.tags }}</p>
              </div>
              
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript/Vue

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      header: "My BookWriting Tool",
      post: {},
      index: 0,
      newPost: {},
      newComment: [],
      readingPost: {},
      perPage: 9,
      pagination: {},
      pinned: 0,
      //pinned: null,
      posts: []
    };
  },
...
```

I can say that posts work as follows:

```js
posts: [
  {"id":4,"title":"4 pinned","pinned":true},
  {"id":5,"title":"5","pinned":false},
  {"id":3,"image":"https://picsum.photos/350/250?random=3","title":"Third","fullText":"Only truncates when text is longer than 2 lines. :)","pinned":false},
  {"id":2,"image":"https://picsum.photos/350/450?random=2","title":"Second","fullText":"Second post, not gonna add much. Second post, not gonna add much. Second post, not gonna add much. Second post, not gonna add much. Second post, not gonna add much. Second post, not gonna add much. ","tags":"second, tag","pinned":false},
  {"id":1,"image":"https://picsum.photos/430?random=1","title":"First","fullText":"First one okay. First one okay. First one okay. First one okay. First one okay. First one okay. First one okay. First one okay. ","tags":"first, tag, echo"}
]
```

Comment: No issues, please also accept it when you can.

Comment: It says I have to wait until tomorrow, which I then will :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works :)

```html
<div :class="post.pinned ? 'pinned' : 'blue'">
<h3 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h3></div>
```

WORKS!